# Passing date parameter in dymanic sql

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, dynamic-sql

This procedure was working good until i decided to get the report by date range.
The CreatedDate column in table is of datatype datetime. I'm passing the dates from c# as text eg: '2014-09-31'. The argument can also be empty sometime.

Now I do not get any result. I also tried to convert into varchar instead of date. Where am i going wrong.

If i just remove the 'added' part, query works fine again.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE GetReport
(
 @StartDate varchar(10),
 @EndDate varchar(10)
)
AS
BEGIN
 SET NOCOUNT ON;
     IF (@StartDate = '')
     SET @StartDate = NULL 

     IF (@EndDate = '')
     SET @EndDate = NULL

DECLARE @query VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @questions VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @questions = STUFF((....some code)  

SET @query = 'SELECT * FROM
                    (
                      SELECT asq.QuestionText, asa.Comments, 
                             ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY asa.FkQuestionId
                             ORDER BY asa.Comments) Seq
                             FROM Answers AS asa 
                             LEFT JOIN Questions AS asq ON    
                             asa.FkQuestionId = asq.QuestionId

                  //---added this part------
                    WHERE (asa.CreatedDate) >= CONVERT(date,'+@StartDate+') 
                    OR CONVERT(date,'+@StartDate+') IS NULL)
                    AND (asa.CreatedDate) <= CONVERT(date,'+@EndDate+') OR 
                    CONVERT(date,'+@EndDate+') IS NULL)
                 //---end------

                     ) AS t    
                     PIVOT
                        (
                          MIN(t.Comments)    
                          FOR t.QuestionText IN ('+@questions+')    
                        ) AS pvt'                       
            EXECUTE (@query)
END
```

Comment: Why do you need a dynamic query??

Comment: You really should be using datetime datatypes instead of strings.

Answer (score 1):

If your column `CreatedDate` is datatype datetime then you need to cast to date to remove the time portion. The time portion may not be 00:00:00

```
                WHERE ( CAST(asa.CreatedDate AS DATE) >= CONVERT(date,'+@StartDate+') 
                OR CONVERT(date,'+@StartDate+') IS NULL) )
                AND ( CAST(asa.CreatedDate AS DATE) <= CONVERT(date,'+@EndDate+') OR 
                CONVERT(date,'+@EndDate+') IS NULL) )
```